# This function turns the list <void> instead of swapping the value, why?

Tags: scheme, hashtable, swap

So this function is supposed to swap out x, which is also the key for the hash table, with the value of that key from the hash table, but when the list somehow becomes < void >. Why?

```
(define (var-helper L)
       (for-each (lambda (x) (when (hash-has-key? *variables* x)
             (swap x (hash-ref *variables* x) L)))
             L))
```

Here's the swap function I'm using:

```
(define (swap x y L)
   (cond ((empty? L) '()) 
         ((list? (car L))
            (cons (swap x y (car L))
            (swap x y (cdr L))))
         ((eq? x (car L)) 
            (cons y (swap x y (cdr L))))
        ((cons (car L) (swap x y (cdr L))))))
```

Comment: What is the definition of swap?

Comment: It searches a list (L) for x. If x exists, it replaces it with the new value, in this case (hash-ref *variables* x).

Comment: I added the swap function to my question for reference ^^^^

Comment: `for-each` is like `map`, but without keeping the result from each item. The result of it is implementation dependant and according to the report (standard) it's undefined. `<void>` is a perfectly undefined value.   `swap` does not change anything but produce a new value with everything `eq?` x replaced with `y`. Since you are using `for-each` the result of `swap` is never used, but discarded.

Comment: I tried map as well, but got a similar error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define (var-helper L)
  (map (lambda (x) (swap x (hash-ref *variables* x) L))
       (filter (lambda (x) (hash-has-key? *variables* x))
               L)))
```

As mentioned in the comments, `for-each` doesn't build a new list as result, it just processes each element, returning an undefined value (`<void>` in this case). That's why you should use `map` to return a new list as output.

Also, notice that you must handle the case when one of the elements isn't present in the hash table - for instance, `filter`ing them out first. And one last thing - there's something wrong with the `swap` function, the last condition is missing the `else` part.

Comment: there's still one problem: when the if statement is false, it appends x to the list but it shouldnt be so it should look like (+ 1 3) and  but it looks like (+ (+ 1 3) 3) instead.

Comment: is there a way to do nothing to the list when its false

Comment: @ghostofrasputin you didn't mention that in the initial question. You have to solve the problem in two steps - first, `filter` the elements that you want to process; second, process them. I updated my answer.

Comment: @ghostofrasputin then write a helper procedure for that, sorry, that's a different question outside the scope of this one.